# auth0 reactjs redirect to different route if not logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I'm learning Auth0 + react and am specifically looking at the example here:
https://github.com/auth0-blog/auth0-react-sample

On the home.js page there is a code block:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import { Hero, HomeContent } from "../components";


const Home = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Hero />
    <hr />
    <HomeContent />
  </Fragment>
);

export default Home;
```

What I want to do is render the JSX (? I think that's the the term) `<Hero />` if the user is authenticated and render something that says "User not authenticated for this" if the user is not logged in.

I was able to get the first part working by changing the file to:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import { Hero, HomeContent } from "../components";
import ProtectedRoute from "../auth/protected-route";


const Home = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <ProtectedRoute path="/Hero" component={Hero} />
    {/*<Hero />*/}
    <hr />
    <HomeContent />
  </Fragment>
);

export default Home;
```

However I'm at a loss how to render a "Not logged in" div. I can make a separate view easily enough and make it a route but I'm lost as to how to do the if/else block?

Apologies if silly question, coming from the python world.

Thanks!

#Edit 1:
The protected route component is below:

```
// src/auth/protected-route.js

import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { Loading } from "../components/index";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component, ...args }) => (
  <Route
    component={withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
      onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
    })}
    {...args}
  />
);

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: Can you share the ProtectedRoute component/hoc also?

Comment: @RahulSharma Done

Comment: I believe you can pull `isAuthenticated` out of the `useAuth0` hook in `app.js:12`, allowing you to construct a code path manually. Otherwise the proper way Auth0 probably wants to work is to use the options for `withAuthenticationRequired` https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/blob/master/src/with-authentication-required.tsx

Comment: @LyndenNoye Not quite the same thing. I want a component to replace another component. So the default is "not logged in" and once a user logs in, that component is replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you need, we can call the `useAuth0` hook again in the Home component to get the auth state. Try the following:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0()
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isAuthenticated ? <Hero /> : "User not authenticated for this"}
      <hr />
      <HomeContent />
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

The `useAuth0` hook is actually just a Context API consumer: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/blob/master/src/use-auth0.tsx

The context provider `Auth0ProviderWithHistory` is rendered in `index.js` and wraps our `App` component, so we can call the `useAuth0` hook anywhere in our `App` to grab any of the Auth0 state or helper functions.

If you're not across the React Context API, here are the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html